# How to scope efficiently javascript et css on a rails appliacation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, scope

I had a lot of trouble to scope my javascript and css files on my rails app. By scoping, I mean :

**How to deal with java-script and CSS only used in one page or one controller ?**

I tried some solutions but they were all complicated and not so elegant :

- I saw some advices like this one : including my .js file directly on my .erb file like so :

  ```
  <% content_for :head do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  <% end %>
  ```

  and then yield that in the application layout. But that means doing one more request to the server in order to get the .js file.
  I think it is important to stay with only **one .js file and one .css file** for the application, created by the **asset pipeline**
- I saw some other advices like testing if my HTML tag was present on the DOM with the [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) method of jquery. That's still mean testing on every page if on particular tag is present (knowing it will be present in only one or two pages).

I found a solution that's is easy to implement and, in my point of view, elegant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Requirements:

in your application layout change

```
<body>
```

to

```
<body class="#{controller_name}_#{action_name}">
```

The body will have a different class for every page. For example, on a blogging application with an *article_controller* and an *index* action on this controller, the body will be :

```
<body class='article_index'>
```

### CSS Scoping

The CSS scoping is almost immediate. If you have some styles that only need to be rendered on a certain page (let's say *article#index*), you just need to ad in you SCSS file :

```
body.article_index {
# CSS STYLE HERE
}
```

You don't need to add very long class names everywhere.

### Javascript scoping

You need to download [jquery-readyselector](https://github.com/Verba/jquery-readyselector). This plugin  extends `.ready()` to provide a nice syntax for page-specific script :

```
$('.article_index').ready(function () {
    alert("I'm on article#index !");
});
```

An other great things about this plugin is that it is working with *turbolink*.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500641/javascript-doesnt-execute-when-navigating-from-page-to-page) you can see one of my previous question about *turbolink*. In order to make my java-script work on page loading AND on page change, someone proposed to me something like that :

```
// accommodate Turbolinks
$(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
// STUFF
});
```

But sometime (on the first page loaded), the function was **executed twice** (one for `ready`, one for `page:change`), now I just use *jquery-readyselector* like so :

```
// accommodate Turbolinks
$('nav.nav').ready(function() {
// STUFF
});
```

and the function will be executed once on every scenario.

I hope this will helps someone.

Comment: First found [this solution explained like so](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails/), but your answer clicks better in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Conditional Layout**

If you only want to show `css` / `js` assets on a specific page, you'll either be best calling the asset in the `view` itself (which *isn't* recommended), or just set a condition in your `layout` to call the files you need:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<html>
   <head>
      <% if controller_name == "test" && action_name == "index" %>
         ...
      <% end %>
   </head>
</html>
```

Something which will help you are the [`controller_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class) and `action_name` helpers - they will give you the reference to the `controller` or `action` your page has rendered.

--

**Turbolinks**

In regards to your answer, I don't understand what you're trying to propose. There's a problem here:

```
$('nav.nav').ready(function() { //-> wrong syntax
```

If you want to incorporate [`Turbolinks`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), you need to use either the [`event`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) hooks of `Turbolinks`, or javascript delegation:

```
var nav_ready = function() {
   // do stuff here
};

$(document).on("page:load ready", nav_ready);
```